# How to Copy values from a Datagridview selected row to textboxes

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to select a datagridview row and copy values to 3 textbox.

I tried this code (it works in another my project), but I got an error. This is the code:

```
private void DataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.DataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            textBox1.Text = row.Cells["HomeNM"].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = row.Cells["HostNM"].Value.ToString();
            fromTxt.Text = row.Cells["odd1NM"].Value.ToString();

        }
    }
```

This is my error:

```
Error 1 ' bexscraping.Form1 ' does not contain a definition of ' DataGridView2 ' and has not been found no extension method ' DataGridView2 ' accepting a first argument of type ' bexscraping.Form1 ' . Probably missing a using directive or a reference to an assembly.
```

I don't know where is the error- Any idea?

**EDIT:** I forgot to initialize my datagridview;M now my code is working! Anyway thanks!

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code, one thing I could ask, do you have `DataGridView` by name `DataGridView2` in your project ?

Comment: The correct name is: dataGridView2

Comment: That's what the problem is, try using ` DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];`

Comment: I found the solution, see my edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure that the gridView is initialzed. Then try this**

```
private void dataGridView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count>0){
           textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["HomeNM"].Value.ToString();
           textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["HostNM"].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["odd1NM"].Value.ToString();
    }
   } // haha
```

Comment: I found the solution with your advice about dgv inizialized, but you miss a "}" in your code. Please see my edit. Thanks!

Comment: but you got me, right !! technically you should accept my answer, then :)

Comment: Done, but remeber to update your code in your answer closing it with another "}"   ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that the name DataGridView2 is correct.

Then open the designer, click on DataGridView2 and in the properties make sure that Design -> GenerateMember is set to true.

Did this help ?

Answer (score 0):

try this sir.

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
{
 txtbox1.text = datagridview1.currentrow.cells["cellname"].value
 . . . 'and so on.
}
```

hope this will solve your error

Comment: ahh okay. By the way try using `currentrow` to shorten and make clean your code :) just an advise